# When can a state of the form $\rho=\sum_i p_i\lvert\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i\rvert$ be a pure state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

I know that in general a "non-pure" state described by : $$ \rho = \sum_i p_i |\psi_i\rangle\langle \psi_i| $$ **can't** be written as $ \rho = | \phi\rangle\langle \phi|$.

But if we exclude the obvious when all the $ | \psi_i \rangle $ are identical, is it still possible?

In fact for me it is not obvious at first sight if I have $$ \rho = \sum_i p_i |\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i| $$ to be sure that it is or it is not a pure state without calculating $ \textrm{Tr}(\rho^2)$ for example. And I don't know if excepted the obvious case with identical $ | \psi_i \rangle $, such a state is necessarily non pure ?

So to summarise: if I have a density matrix state with different $ |\psi_i \rangle$, do you agree with me if I say that it still ***can*** be a pure state (and the only way to know it is to compute $\textrm{Tr}(\rho^2)$ )?

Comment: You can answer your question by computing $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho^2)$ for the generic sum and think about whether or not that can be 1 if more than one of the $p_i$ is non-zero.

Comment: Hint: For counterexamples, look at the [Bloch sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere).

Comment: I tried to do this but I don't see how to simplify the sum :

$Tr(\rho^2)=\sum_{k,k',p} p_k p_k' <u_p|\psi_k><\psi_k|\psi_k'><\psi_k'|u_p>$

Comment: If there is more than one $p_i>0$, and the corresponding $\psi_i$ are different, the resulting $\rho$ has rank $\ge2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me rephrase your question.

Suppose that $\rho$ is a **pure state**, i.e., it is written as $$\rho =|\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$$ for some unit vector $\psi$.

Your question is the following.

**Q1**. Is it possible to find a set of  vectors $\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n$ satisfying  $$n>1\:,$$ $||\phi_i||=1$, possibly $\langle \phi_i|\phi_j \rangle \neq 0$ for some $i\neq j$, and numbers $q_1, \ldots, q_n$ with $0< q_i <1$ and $\sum_i q_i =1$, such that
$$|\psi\rangle \langle \psi| = \sum_{i=1}^n q_i|\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i|$$
and $|\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i| \neq |\phi_j\rangle \langle \phi_j|$
for some $i\neq j$?

As far as I understand you already know the following general result.

**THEOREM1**. *Consider an operator $\rho: H \to H$ where $H$ is a complex Hilbert space and $\rho$ is trace class, non-negative and $tr(\rho)=1$.
Under these hypotheses, $\rho$ is a pure state if and only if $tr(\rho) = tr(\rho^2)$.*

As a consequence, since the operator  $\sum_{i=1}^n q_i|\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i|$ is trace class, non-negative with unit trace,  **Q1** may be restated as follows.

**Q2**. Is it possible to find a set of  vectors $\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n$ with $$n>1\:,$$ $||\phi_i||=1$, possibly $\langle \phi_i|\phi_j \rangle \neq 0$ for some $i\neq j$, and numbers $q_1, \ldots, q_n$ with $0< q_i <1$ and $\sum_i q_i =1$, such that
$$tr\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n q_i|\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i|\right)^2\right] =1$$
and $|\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i| \neq |\phi_j\rangle \langle \phi_j|$
for some $i\neq j$?

The answer to **Q2** is always **negative** as soon as $n>1$, and thus

*it is not necessary to compute the trace of $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n q_i|\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i|\right)^2$, just knowing that $n>1$ is enough* to decide that the state $\sum_{i=1}^n q_i|\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i|$ is **not** pure unless $|\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i|=|\phi_j \rangle \langle \phi_j|$ for all $i,j$.

The proof is the following. First of all let me introduce the **Hilbert-Schmidt scalar product** between Hilbert Schmidt operators, and thus trace class operators in particular,
$$(\rho|\rho')_{HS} := tr(\rho^*\rho')\:.$$ 
The associated norm reads
$$||\rho||_{HS}= \sqrt{tr(\rho^*\rho)}\:.$$

Theorem1 can equivalently be restated as follows.

**THEOREM2**. *Consider an operator $\rho: H \to H$ where $H$ is a complex Hilbert space and $\rho$ is trace class, non-negative and $tr(\rho)=1$.
Under these hypotheses, $\rho$ is a pure state if and only if $||\rho||_{HS}=1$.*

Now consider an operator $\rho: H \to H$ of the form
$$\rho = \sum_{i=1}^n q_i \rho_i\tag{0}$$
where $\rho_i := |\phi_i \rangle \langle \phi_i|$ with $\phi_i$ and $q_i$ as in **Q2**.  $\rho$ is trace class, non-negative and we want to check if $||\rho||_{HS}=1$ is possible when $n>1$. This condition is equivalent to saying that $\rho$ is pure.

We can always restrict ourselves to deal with a **real** vector space of trace class operators, since our trace class operators are self-adjoint and the linear combinations we consider are constructed with real (and non-negative) numbers. The scalar product $(\:|\:)_{HS}$ becomes a standard real (symmetric) scalar product in that real subspace.

The crucial observation is that, as it happens in every real vector space equipped with a real scalar product,
$$\left|\left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right|\right| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n ||x_i||\tag{1}$$
and 
*"$\leq$" is replaced for "$=$" if and only if  $x_i  = \alpha_i x$ for some fixed $x$ and non negative numbers $\alpha_i$ where $i=1,\ldots,n$.*

In other words, 
$$\left|\left|\sum_{i=1}^n q_i \rho_i\right|\right|_{HS} \leq \sum_{i=1}^n ||q_i \rho_i||_{HS}\tag{2}$$
and 
*"$\leq$" is replaced for "$=$" if and only if  $q_i \rho_i  = \alpha_i T$ for some fixed $T$ and non negative numbers $\alpha_i$  where $i=1,\ldots,n$.*

Since we know that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n ||q_i \rho_i||_{HS}= \sum_{i=1}^n q_i ||\rho_i||_{HS} = \sum_{i=1}^n q_i 1 = \sum_{i=1}^n q_i =1$$
we conclude that If $\rho$ in (0) is pure, then the sign "$\leq$" in (2) is replaced by "$=$", so that $q_i\rho_i = \alpha_i T$ for some fixed operator $T$ and reals $\alpha_i$. Taking the trace of both sides $q_i = \alpha_i tr(T)$  where $tr(T) \neq 0$ because $q_i \neq 0$. Re-defining $T \to \rho_0 := \frac{1}{tr T}T$, we have found that there is a positive trace-class operator $\rho_0$ with unit trace such that $\rho_i= \rho_0$ and furthermore $tr \rho_0^2 = tr \rho_i^2 =1$ so that $\rho_0$ is pure and thus it can be written as $\rho_0 := |\phi_0 \rangle \langle \phi_0|$ for some unit vector $\phi_0$.
Summing up, we have obtained that

*if $\rho$ in (0) is pure, then 
 $|\phi_i\rangle \langle \phi_i|= |\phi_0 \rangle \langle \phi_0|$ for all $i=1,\ldots, n$.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you assumed that the $ | \Psi_i > $ are orthogonal here : if they are orthogonal then a pure state is also a non pure state only if it is written $ | \Psi_i >< \Psi_i | $. My question was more general with any family of $\Psi_i$.

Comment: @user3183950 while I totally understand the confusion, note that it does not change the answer above. Every density matrix is diagonal in **some** orthonormal basis $\big\{|\phi_i\rangle\big\}$, which may have nothing to do with your $\big\{|\psi_i\rangle\big\}$ therefore $\operatorname{Tr}\rho^2 = \operatorname{Tr}\rho = 1$ is both necessary and sufficient.

Comment: The structure of this answer is a bit hard to parse - it kind of looks like proof by contradiction but then it kind of switches tracks. Maybe make it a bit clearer at the beginning what you're going to show, and how?

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty user3183950 I completely changed my answer since I suspected I had completely misunderstood the question. Please let me know if now my answer is more appropriate.

Comment: @Valter Yeah, that's a lot clearer.

Comment: Thank you a lot. In conclusion the answer to my question is : it is not possible to have at the same time a pure state and a non-pure state if we exclude the obvious cases pi=1, pj=0.

I thought again to the problem in a more physical way and do you agree with me if I say the following :

If I have a pure state, there exist a measurement for which I am totally sure of the result of the measurement (I consider $\Psi$ as an eigenvector of an observable).

Whereas, if I have a non pure state I never can 100% sure of the result of any measurement.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. However everything we are saying is true in the absence of superselection rules, as I have assumed in developing my reasoning.

Comment: Does this hold for $n\to \infty$?

Comment: Yes, everything can be generalized in infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Let us introduce the notation $\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}P_i\equiv \lvert\psi_i\rangle\!\langle\psi_i\rvert$. Note that each $P_i$ is a (normal) projector with unit trace.

The question is then equivalent to the following:

> *when can a convex combination of (normal) trace-$1$ projectors $P_i$ be a trace-$1$ projector?*

The answer is that this is the case *if and only if* the projections are all equal (or in other words, it is never true, except for the trivial cases).

To show this, suppose $\rho=\sum_i p_i P_i$ with $p_i>0, \sum_i p_i=1$.

A normalised state $\rho$ is pure if and only if $\rho^2=\rho$, and if and only if $\tr(\rho^2)=\tr(\rho)$.
We have
$$ \rho^2 = \sum_i p_i^2 P_i + \sum_{i\neq j}p_i p_j P_i P_j.$$
and thus
$$\tr(\rho^2) = \sum_i p_i^2 + 2 \sum_{i<j}p_i p_j\tr(P_i P_j)\le \left(\sum_i p_i\right)^2=1,$$
where the inequality becomes an identity if and only if $\tr(P_i P_j)=1$ for all $i,j$, that is, if and only if $P_i=P_j$.

---

Another way to prove this is to pass by the eigendecomposition of $\rho$.

If $\rho$ is a trace-$1$ projection, then there is some vector $v$ such that $\rho v=v$. This would imply $\sum_i p_i P_i v=v$, and thus $\sum_i p_i \langle v,P_i v\rangle=1$. But $\langle v,P_i v\rangle\in[0,1]$ for all $i$, and thus the only way for such convex combination to equal $1$ is that all terms do, *i.e.* $\langle v,P_i v\rangle=1$ for all $i$, and thus $P_i=vv^\dagger$ for all $i$.

Yet another argument is to observe that a state is pure if and only its rank is $1$, and if and only if its support is one-dimensional.
For a convex combination (more generally, a sum with positive coefficients) of rank-$1$ projections to have one-dimensional support, each component must also have the same (one-dimensional) support, hence $P_i=P_j$.