# Is every idempotent density operator the sum of orthogonal projections?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, density-operator

Can every idempotent density operator be written in the form $$\sum_ic_i|i\rangle\langle i|,$$ where $\{|i\rangle\}$ is an orthonormal set and $\{c_i\}$ is a set of coefficients (Edit: Without assuming that the vector space on which the density operator operates is finite dimensional)?

It seems like people are assuming that when proving that a density operator is idempotent if and only if it represents a pure state (for example here: [Necessary and sufficient conditions for a pure state](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/488397/necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-a-pure-state)).

Comment: Density operators are Hermitian, so....

Comment: Think about what "diagonalizing a matrix" means, and what the comment above mine is saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, density operators are self-adjoint.

In the case of a finite dimensional vector space, every self-adjoint operator has an orthonormal set of eigenvectors (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).

Alternatively (instead of assuming a finite dimensional vector space), we can prove the statement for compact operators (see exercise 6 in chapter 19 of [1]).

[1] Brian Hall, Quantum Theory for Mathematicians