# What is the relation between purity and ${\rm Tr}(\rho^2)$, for a density matrix?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator, quantum-states

I would like to understand the equivalence for a state $\psi$ to be **pure** and its density matrix $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ having the property $$\operatorname{trace} \rho^2=1.$$ For this I should multiply 2 matrices and look at the result trace. I do not know 2 things, how the matrices should look like and whether $\psi$ should be normalized (and allowing speak about vicinity of the trace with the number 1). Any hints?

Comment: Regarding normalization: Any density is, by definition, normalized in the sense that $\mathrm{Tr} \rho=1$. Now convince yourself that for $P_\psi:=|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$ we have $\mathrm{Tr}P_\psi=\langle \psi|\psi\rangle$. So what do you conclude regarding the normalization of $|\psi\rangle$ for a pure density matrix? Regarding the matrix: Choose any orthonormal basis $\{|n\rangle\}_{n=1,\ldots,\dim H<\infty}$ and compute $\rho_{nm}:=\langle n|\rho|m\rangle$. However, IMHO it would be much easier to argue with the spectral decomposition of $\rho$ here.

Comment: To add: One direction is *very* simple: You should proof that if $\rho$ is pure, i.e. $\rho=P_\psi$ for some suitable $P_\psi$, then $\rho=\rho^2$ and from the trace condition of density matrices you obtain the desired result. For the converse direction, write down the spectral decomposition, compute $\rho^2$ and the trace. You should notice something. And, btw., this can be generalized to infinite dimensions (but requires more work of course).

Comment: @JasonFunderberker I'm a newbie to the spectral decomposition. In fact I do not even know what is $\langle n | \rho | m\rangle$. I understand that $|\psi\rangle$ is a form from $H$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and your $\operatorname{Tr}P_{\psi}$ is that complex number evaluated at $\langle\psi |$. Am I correct at least with the bra-ket notation ? So what is $\langle n | \rho | m\rangle$ before I google the spectral decomposition notion ?

Comment: No. In the bra-ket notation $|\psi\rangle \in H$ (or, if you want it is a map from $\mathbb C$ to $H$)  and $\langle \psi|: H\longrightarrow \mathbb C$. But you don't have to use the bra-ket notation at all here. You might be interested in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/488397/is-idempotency-rho2-rho-a-necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-rho-t?rq=1), which is basically the answer to your question (however, I don't know if this is 'at the right level').

Comment: A density matrix is the one of a pure state if and only if its [von Neumann entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy) $-\operatorname{tr}(\rho\log\rho)$ is zero.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker OK, I've switched the bra-ket notation.Which function is, how it is defined $|\psi\rangle$ from $\mathbb{C}$ to $H$ given $\psi$ ?

Comment: The comment section is not really suited for long discussions...Anyway, one *can* define, for $\psi \in H$ given, a function $|\psi\rangle:\mathbb C \longrightarrow H$ as $|\psi\rangle(\lambda) = \lambda \psi$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb C$. But this is of no use here, really. As I said, for the proof you consider (and for basically everything else, because it is just notation) you don't need the bra-ket notation. You can work with whatever notation you want, but for better or worse, the bra-ket notation is often used by physicists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to understand the equivalence for a state $\psi$ to be **pure** and its density matrix $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ having the property $$\operatorname{trace} \rho^2=1.$$

The density matrix is given, in some basis $|\psi_i\rangle$ by:
$$
\rho = \sum_i p_i |\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|
$$

This means that:
$$
Tr(\rho^2) = \sum_i p_i^2\;.
$$

Because of the condition $\sum_i p_i = 1$, the largest value that $Tr(\rho^2)$ can take on is 1. This largest value is attained when $p_i=1$ for exactly one value of $i$ and zero otherwise.

For example, if $p_i=1/2$ for exactly two $i$ values then $Tr(\rho^2)=1/4$, which is less than 1.

Comment: Good explanation. Is the trace of $\rho=\sum_i p_i |\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|$ 1 by definition or does it use the fact that $|\psi\rangle$ is normalized ? How can I compute Trace ($\rho$) for small $n$ from $\psi_i$ ?

Comment: @user2925716 : By definition of *any* density matrix, $\mathrm{Tr}\rho=1$. Now in general there can be many ensembles giving rise to the same density matrix. However, in all cases, one needs that $\langle \psi_i,\psi_i\rangle=1$; however, they don't need to be mutual orthogonal. What do you mean computing the trace for small $n$? -The trace always equals one.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Right, so my assumption that $\psi$ is normalized was correct. I just wanted to compute Tr for $n=2$ explicitly to see what's going on when I multiply $|\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|$ with itself and then look at Tr (everything for generic $\psi=(z_1,z_2)$).

Comment: @user2925716 I see. For that you could expand $\psi$ in an orthonormal basis $\psi_n$ and compute $\langle \psi_n,\rho\,\psi_m\rangle$ (this is the matrix representation of $\rho$ in this basis) and then just sum the diagonal elements.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker I've tried but failed on the paper. Could you kindly do this for me for $n=2$ and included this as a part of an Answer ? At the same time, I still do not know what is this $$\langle n|\rho | m\rangle .$$

Comment: You should ask a separate question then. I don't fully understand your problem, sorry. Ignore the bra-ket notation. Given an operator $A$ (on a finite-dimensional complex Hilbert space) - how do you compute its matrix representation? This has nothing to do with quantum mechanics. Do you know what is meant by $P_\psi:=|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$? If not: It means that for any vector $\phi$ we have $P_\psi(\phi) = \langle \psi,\phi\rangle \psi$. So again: Perhaps it is the best to ask a separate, new question where you explicitly explain at which step you have problems.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker May I include my problem as an edit to this question ? The system on SE doesn't seem to allow me new question .

Comment: @user2925716 As it is a different problem (IMO), you should ask a different question. But this is your question, so do whatever you want... I don't understand why you should be unable to open a new question. If so, you need to talk to a moderator I guess.

Comment: @user2925716 Don't edit your question at this point, since you already selected an answer. Just a new question. It should be allowed.